# Bootstrap 5 Dropdowns: Get selected dropdown item value in the dropdown button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have a simple issue with my dropdown button while I'm trying to get the selected dropdown item to the dropdown button value.

The Flag Icon and Text should be changed dynamically I made some examples but as I see it's not working as I expected.

> The only issue that I have is the flag icon not changed dynamically

Live Example: https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/wvdemKz

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us me-1"></span> <span>English</span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us me-1"></span> <span>English</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr me-1"></span> <span>French</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-es me-1"></span> <span>Spanich</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-sa me-1"></span> <span>Arabic</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($(".dropdown").length) {
    $(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu .dropdown-item", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
                customClass: {
                    confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
                    cancelButton: "btn btn-danger me-3",
                },
                buttonsStyling: false,
            });
            swalWithBootstrapButtons
                .fire({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Do you really want to change your current language!",
                    icon: "warning",
                    confirmButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle me-1'></i> Yes, I am!",
                    cancelButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-times-circle me-1'></i> No, I'm Not",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    reverseButtons: true,
                    focusConfirm: true,
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
                            $(".dropdown-menu .dropdown-item").removeClass("active");
                            $(this).addClass("active");
                            $(this)
                                .parents(".dropdown")
                                .find(".btn")
                                .html("<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-us me-1'></span>" + $(this).text());
                        }
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: "success",
                            title: "Amazing!",
                            text: "Your current language has been changed successfully.",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 1500,
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace `.html("<span class='flag-icon flag-icon-us me-1'></span>" + $(this).text());` with `.html($(this).html());`, it will give you the desired output

Comment: this was happening becauze you have hardcoded the flag in the code, that is why it was showing us flag on every click, instead of printing image and text seperatly why not print the complete html by .html() function

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, I have just updated the code to get class of clicked option and added to the span in HTML

```js
if ($(".dropdown").length) {
    $(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu .dropdown-item", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cloneflagicon = $(this).find('span.flag-icon').attr('class');
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
                customClass: {
                    confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
                    cancelButton: "btn btn-danger me-3",
                },
                buttonsStyling: false,
            });
            swalWithBootstrapButtons
                .fire({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Do you really want to change your current language!",
                    icon: "warning",
                    confirmButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-check-circle me-1'></i> Yes, I am!",
                    cancelButtonText: "<i class='fas fa-times-circle me-1'></i> No, I'm Not",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    reverseButtons: true,
                    focusConfirm: true,
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
                            $(".dropdown-menu .dropdown-item").removeClass("active");
                            $(this).addClass("active");
                            $(this)
                                .parents(".dropdown")
                                .find(".btn")
                                .html("<span class='"+cloneflagicon+"'></span>" + $(this).text());
                        }
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: "success",
                            title: "Amazing!",
                            text: "Your current language has been changed successfully.",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 1500,
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Bootstrap 5</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.5.0/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us me-1"></span> <span>English</span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us me-1"></span> <span>English</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr me-1"></span> <span>French</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-es me-1"></span> <span>Spanich</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-sa me-1"></span> <span>Arabic</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```